# ActivityLifecycleHelper implementation

Tags: java, android, callback

**Description**

The `ActivityLifecycleHelper` uses `wrap(Context)`to create the class and save a global `Application` field. It then uses `with(ActivityCallbacks)` to register `android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` on the `Application` field. Whenever `onActivityResumed(Activity)` is triggered the class calls a null  `OnSaved(Bundle)`. Whenever `onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity, Bundle)` is triggered the class calls a saved/null `OnSaved(Bundle)`. It then unregisters the `android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` when `onActivityDestroyed(Activity)` is triggered. Finally, it returns the base context of the `Application` field.

**ActivityLifecycleHelper.class**

```
public class ActivityLifecycleHelper {

    public interface ActivityCallbacks {
        void OnSaved(Bundle savedInstance);
    }

    private final Application application;

    private ActivityLifecycleHelper(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public static ActivityLifecycleHelper wrap(Context context) {
        return new ActivityLifecycleHelper(assertApplication(context));
    }

    public Context with(final ActivityCallbacks callbacks) {
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity a, Bundle b) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity a) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity a) {
                callbacks.OnSaved(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity a) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity a) {}

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity a, Bundle b) {
                callbacks.OnSaved(b);
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity a) {
                application.unregisterActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
            }
        });
        return application.getBaseContext();
    }

    private static Application assertApplication(Context context) {
        final Context application = context.getApplicationContext();
        if (application instanceof Application) return (Application) application;
        throw new NullPointerException("Context must be instance of Application");
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
public class Usage implements ActivityLifecycleHelper.ActivityCallbacks {

    private final Context context;

    Usage(Context context) {
        this.context = ActivityLifecycleHelper.wrap(context).with(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnSaved(Bundle savedInstance) {
        // doingit
    }
}
```

**Reasoning**

This is used within a library that when initialized receives a context that will extend from an Application and hooks into any Activity LifeCycle events.

`OnResume()` will allow the library to reset some things and `onSaveInstanceState()` is so the library can rebuild.

**Needed**

Will this approach register/unregister appropriately? Is anything bad design?
 Will this cause any context leaks?

Comment: A minor suggestion, change the `NullPointerException` thrown from `assertApplication(Context)` to `IllegalArgumentException`. Other than that I don't fully understand what you're asking, perhaps you could edit the question to make it clearer?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I just was looking for some validation, I'm still new and have a weak knowledge base. Basically wanted to make sure the code would be acceptable to those more educated than myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It seems like a bad design or I would say not thought through given that you're building a library project which will be used by other apps.

First of all,
in your library initialization, you should ask for `Application` reference rather than `Context` reference.

For example,

if your library has an init method like this,

`MyLibrary.init(Context applicationContext);`

then it should be converted to accept `Application` object like this,

`MyLibrary.init(Application application);`

Then,

inside that `init` method, you should just register your class which is implementing `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`.

`application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(ActivityLifecycleHelper.getInstance());`

Make sure your class is a `singleton`. In your example, your `ActivityLifecycleHelper` class is not a singleton which is definitely a bad design pattern given that you're dealing with global level callbacks and want to initialize only once.

It might look like this,

```
public class ActivityLifecycleHelper implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
private static ActivityLifecycleHelper ourInstance = new ActivityLifecycleHelper();

private ActivityLifecycleHelper() {
}

public static ActivityLifecycleHelper getInstance() {
    return ourInstance;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
}

@Override
public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

}
}
```

Also, I don't understand why you have two classes here. What's the use case of `Usage` class ? Something seems wrong in this two class design.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you want me to elaborate anything.